# Determining Whether a Given Hamiltonian is Conserved

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

in simple terms I'm looking to understand how we can tell whether a given Hamiltonian (or one that we've deduced) is conserved or not? I've tried looking at other similar questions but am not sure I understand as I'm a Mathematician as opposed to a Physicist.

Thanks

Comment: have you already encountered the term Poisson bracket in the context of hamiltonian mechanics? If yes, you might know that in the hamiltonian formalism $\{f,H\}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}$, hence since the Hamiltonian clearly commutes with itself it is conserved if it does not explicitly depend on time

Comment: I have yes, I hadn't made that link! Thanks

Comment: Does the Hamiltonian have explicit time dependence or not?